# Binding Fn-Delete in zsh on Mac OS X

Tags: macos, keyboard, zsh

In zsh, whenever I press Fn+Delete (which is forward delete) a tilde (~) gets inserted. This indicates zsh doesn't have the key bound.

How do I bind it, and make it behave normally (delete in front of the cursor)?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

First figure out what sequence it generates.

`echo "`<kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>V</kbd><kbd>Fn</kbd><kbd>Delete</kbd>`" | od -c`

Then bind that sequence using the normal zsh bind mechanism.

Comment: ~ > echo "~"|od -c     
0000000    ~  \n                                                        
0000002
~ > 

What do I do with this information now?

Comment: @rixth: It's not actually outputting only a tilde. You can't use `echo "~"` , you have to actually follow the directions that **Ignacio** gave you. On my system, it's `^[[3~` (or as `od` outputs: `033 [ 3 ~`). So the command would be `bindkey "^[[3~" delete-char` which would go in your `~/.zshrc`.

Comment: To clarify the above, `ctrl-v` is a special escape sequence that means "insert the next character I press as a literal unescaped character, instead of doing whatever it usually does." Meaning that it doesn't get converted to `~`, but stays as the escape sequence.

Comment: I don't understand how to use the output of the above to derive the bindkey. My output is `0000000    C   t   r   l   V   F   n   D   e   l   e   t   e  \n
0000016`.

Answer (score 5):

For me the above didn't do the trick so I added the following key binding to my `~/.zshrc`:

`bindkey "\e[3~" delete-char`

FYI: I am on a Mac (High Sierra).

Comment: And how to know the code for any other key I want to bind, e.g. Fn+F1? so that I can set the corresponding codes in my `~/.zshrc`.

Comment: You could type `cat` and then type the keys. `Fn+F1` gives me `^[OP` for instance.

Answer (score 2):

`bindkey '`<kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>v</kbd><kbd>Fn</kbd><kbd>Delete</kbd>`' delete-char`

This will bind <kbd>Fn</kbd>+<kbd>Delete</kbd> to delete forward a single character. If the above is not clear, you need to type <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>v</kbd>,
 <kbd>Fn</kbd>+<kbd>Delete</kbd> between typing the quotes. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>v</kbd> allows you type the literal escape escape sequence of whatever key comes after it.

You can put this line in your `~/.zshrc` file.