# Terminal on Mac - Delete key behavior

Tags: mac, terminal, fn-key, backspace

I'd like the delete key (well, the **<kbd>Fn</kbd>+<kbd>Backspace</kbd>** combination) on my Mac to behave the same way in the Terminal as it does normally. That is, **to do forward-delete**. Right now it outputs tilde - at least that's what I can see.

In [Binding Fn-Delete in zsh on Mac OS X](https://superuser.com/questions/169920/binding-fn-delete-in-zsh-on-mac-os-x) I saw some hackery and tried it too:

(pressed [Fn]+[<---] inside the quotes below)

```
$ echo "~" | od -c
0000000   ~  \n
0000002
```

How can I make it behave?

Comment: The comments on [SU 169930](http://superuser.com/questions/169920/binding-fn-delete-in-zsh-on-mac-os-x/169930#169930) seem fairly clear: You should be using Control-v before pressing Fn-BackSpace, which will probably show up as `033 [ 3 ~` from *od*. Then use `bindkey "^[[3~" delete-char` to bind what *Terminal* sends to a function in *zsh*. Does that not work for you?

Comment: Tried to add `bindkey "^[[3~" delete-char` into my ~/.profile, restarted Terminal, and tells me it doesn't know `bindkey`. Added it into .zshrc, restarted Terminal, and nothing happens. I don't really think I'm using _zsh_. Or is it Mac's default shell? I'm an amateur in these things... :)

Comment: You can check your shell with `dscl . read /Users/$USER UserShell`. The default is *bash*. You can change your default shell with `chsh -s /bin/bash`. You can change just the shell used in *Terminal* in its preferences (Settings tool bar button, then Shell tab, change Run Command to (e.g.) `/bin/zsh`).

Comment: Yes, my default is bash. I tried zsh and it seems to work the way I want it to. Does the bash have a way to achieve the same result?

Comment: For the csh or tcsh shell, see this link: https://www.tomica.net/blog/2017/10/fix-delete-key-in-csh-or-tcsh/

Answer (score 19, accepted):

The answer to the question to which you linked shows how to find the control sequence *Terminal* sends when you press <kbd>Fn</kbd><kbd>Backspace</kbd>: `echo '`<kbd>Control</kbd><kbd>V</kbd> <kbd>Fn</kbd><kbd>Backspace</kbd>`' | od -c`.
The <kbd>Control</kbd><kbd>V</kbd> is critical to prevent special interpretation of the (likely) initial ESC character.

*Terminal* probably sends the four byte sequence `ESC [ 3 ~`.

The question to which you linked was asking about *zsh*. The comment on the answer gives the command to bind the sequence in *zsh*, i.e:

```
bindkey "^[[3~" delete-char
```

(usually in `~/.zhsrc`).

However, *bash* is the default shell on Mac OS X, so the command to bind a key (and the functions available for binding) will be different if you are using *bash*: `bind '"\e[3~": delete-char'`. You will probably want to put this in a *bash* startup file<sup>1</sup>.

If you find that you are using *bash*, but you want to use *zsh* instead, then there are two ways to change your effective shell:

- Use `chsh -s /bin/zsh` to change your default shell.
  This will change the shell that *Terminal* starts as well as the shell started for other login sessions (e.g. logins through SSH).
- Configure just *Terminal* to use a different shell in *Terminal*’s preferences.
  **Terminal** > **Preferences…**, **Settings** tool bar button, then the **Shell** tab,
  change **Run Command** to (e.g.) `/bin/zsh -l`.

---

<sup>1</sup> Usually `~/.bashrc`, but you can also put a related line (`"\e[3~": delete-char`) in `~/.inputrc` instead. If you put it your `.bashrc`, you will want to make sure that you also have a line like `source ~/.bashrc` in `~/.bash_profile`, or `~/.bash_login` (if you have neither, then create the former; if you already have exactly one of them, then use the one you have; if you have both, then you should fix that since probably only the former is being used).

Comment: Excellent explanation. Thank you! (oh, and it worked. :) )

Comment: Nice simple answer for me. Just put this in `~/.zshrc` on the server