# Fn + Delete on Mac no longer works

Tags: mac, keyboard-shortcuts

I've used the Fn + Delete keyboard shortcut for years on my Macs, and for some reason it's no longer working on my MacBook Pro with Touch Bar. Now when I press Fn + Delete on my keyboard, it behaves exactly the same as when I just press Delete by itself. I expect it to do a forward delete, rather than backward delete.

I know the Function key isn't completely broken since it changes what appears in the Touch Bar and works in other contexts.

I'm running macOS Mojave 10.14.3 on my MacBook Pro (15-inch, 2016). I'm not sure where to look for a setting to fix this. And if I haven't messed up a setting, I'm not sure which apps to look for to blame for this so I can quit or uninstall. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you using USB Overdrive, and is it the latest version?

Comment: @harrymc Unless USB Overdrive comes preinstalled on macOS, I'm not using it.

Comment: That was a far shot. Does "Control + D" work for you as Forward delete? Are you using the bash shell? If that key binding has been lost you might need to recreate it (see [example](https://superuser.com/questions/288684/terminal-on-mac-delete-key-behavior)).

Comment: @harrymc "Control + D" does work for me as forward delete in all my apps. I'd like "Fn + Delete" to do the same.

Comment: Are you using the bash shell?

Comment: @harrymc Yes I am.

Comment: Try in bash the command `bind '"\e[3~": delete-char'`. If it helps you may put it in `~/.bashrc`.

Comment: Any comment about the above?