# git --interactive keybinding problem for left/right/delete

Tags: mac, bash, git, zsh

I am using zsh on my Mac and after some `bindkey` trickery I managed to get left/right/delete/backspace to work on zsh (and bash). In `git --interactive`, this does not work correctly though.

When I try to commit things in interactive mode, only backspace works. When I press left, right, delete I get the ANSI escape sequences for those keys: `^[[D ^[[C ^[[3~`. When I look for these in my bindkey list, they seem to be configured correctly though:

```
% bindkey | \grep -F "^[[D" 
"^[[D" backward-char
% bindkey | \grep -F "^[[C"
"^[[C" forward-char
% bindkey | \grep -F "^[[3~"
"^[[3~" delete-char
```

This occurs both when I use bash as well as when I use zsh. It also happens when I use X11's `xterm` instead of Terminal.app. I have found numerous posts regarding these problems in zsh itself (for example [this forum](http://dbaspot.com/shell/268469-zsh-backspace-headache.html), [this post](http://www.kismith.co.uk/wordpress/index.php/guides/zshosx/) or on [SU itself](https://superuser.com/questions/169920/binding-fn-delete-in-zsh-on-mac-os-x)), but none of them relate to git.

In short: left/right/delete keys *do* work in my shell, but not in `git --interactive`. How can I fix this?

Answer (score 1):

First, special keys are handled by the program itself, not by the tty device. When you press <kbd>Left</kbd>, Terminal.app sends `ESC [D` to *bash*, and interpreting it is up to *bash*'s Readline library.

The only exceptions are the keys listed in `stty -a` – when the tty is in "cooked" mode, it itself interprets such keypresses as Backspace. (Bash and Zsh actually use "raw" mode themselves, but switch temporarily to "cooked" before running a program.)

Second, the shells and `git --interactive` are *completely* unrelated programs. When you run `git`, the shell is suspended. All programs get direct access to the tty device, and each uses its own library for interacting with it – *bash* uses Readline, *zsh* uses its own ZLE, `git --interactive` reads from the terminal directly. Bindings made in *zsh* only apply when *zsh*, not *git*, is reading from terminal.

As I said, `git --interactive` reads from the terminal directly, which means you cannot use Zsh's `bindkey` or Readline's `~/.inputrc` with it. You would have to modify the program to use Readline or a similar library. (Since `git-add--interactive` is a Perl script, you could rewrite parts of it to use Term::ReadLine, but I don't expect it to be accepted upstream.)

Comment: Thanks, that clarifies some things! However, unfortunately this does not solve my problem. Is there a way where I can instruct git (or Perl) to interpret my input correctly? Or: why does it go wrong (on my machine) in the first place?

Comment: @Tim: The post *does* explain why it goes "wrong" -- the task of interpreting escape sequences is left up to the program itself. `git-add--interactive` simply reads a line of text without doing any interpretation -- most likely the developers didn't think it was necessary. (And neither do I.) It's not a problem with Git or Perl (in fact, Perl is just a *programming language*), it's just the way terminals/ttys/programs interact since 1970's or so. As for how to fix it -- see last sentence of last paragraph of the post.)

Comment: Grawity: thanks for the elaboration. I do understand your explanation, except I assume that `git --interactive` printing escape sequences is undesirable behavior. I'm guessing that on other systems this _does_ work as expected, which is why I think the 'problem' might be somewhere on my system, hence my questions.

Comment: @Tim: No. It works the same way on all Unix-like systems (BSD, Mac OS X, Linux... they all follow the same terminal/tty/program distinction - which, by the way, is much older than terminals with arrow keys).